# how to remove specific fields from map using dataweave mule

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component, mule-el, mule-esb

how to remove specific fields from map using dataweave

input:

**{
a:1,
b:2,
c:3,
d:4
}**

I want to remove c and d fields(c and d values are dynamic) and display only 
output

**{
a:1,
b:2
}**

How can we do it in data weave

Answer (score 5):

According to the [Dataweave Reference Documentation](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/dataweave-reference-documentation#remove), you can remove a field from an object. Try using this:

```html
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
payload - "c" - "d"
```

Comment: I want to remove from array [{ a:1, b:2, c:3, d:4 },{ a:5, b:6, c:7, d:8 }] as well.How can we achieve this output should be [{ a:1, b:2 },{ a:5, b:6}]

Comment: without iterating the list

Comment: Please accept this answer if it is correct and create a new one with your next question.

Answer (score 1):

Below code works fine:

```
%dw 2.0
var arr=["c","d"]
output application/json
---
payload filterObject ((value, key, index) -> !(arr contains  (key) as String))
```

You can add/remove the keys that you want to exclude in the variable 'arr'.